# Using axios to submit a form without

Tags: forms, next.js, axios, request

As you can see the code blow I tried to submit the form using [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) but every time i try to submit the form i get a **bad request** error. but if submit this way it works! BUT then it redirect to `/api/user/`.

I'm using [Next.js](https://nextjs.org).

```
        <Form
          // onSubmit={(e) => {
          //   e.preventDefault();
          //   axios({
          //     method: "POST",
          //     url: "/api/user",
          //     data: {
          //       name: e.currentTarget.userName.value,
          //       email: e.currentTarget.userEmail.value,
          //       password: e.currentTarget.usePass.value,
          //     },
          //   }).then((res) => {
          //     prompt("Success", JSON.stringify(res.data));
          //   });
          // }}
          action="/api/user"
          method="POST"
        >
```

Comment: try to console.log to check the correctness of e.currentTarget data, for example I see that "e.currentTarget.usePass.value", maybe you it should be "usePass > userPass"

Comment: well, it's a typo but what I'm talking about is "How to send form data to the data base without reloading the page, and using the `axios` package.